# Dockerfile FROM --platform option

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Dockerfile [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) states that there is possibility to pass `--platform` option in `FROM` instruction like this:

```
FROM [--platform=<platform>] <image> [AS <name>]
```

In my dockerfile I have following statements:

```
ARG arch
FROM --platform linux/${arch} bounz/hgbe.base
```

where [`bounz/hgbe.base`](https://hub.docker.com/r/bounz/hgbe.base/tags) image has two os/arch variants: `linux/amd64` and `linux/arm/v7`.

But trying to build an image using this dockerfile I get an error:

```
$ docker build -f hgbe.dockerfile --build-arg arch=amd64 -t bounz/hgbetest:amd64-0.1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  12.29kB
Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 2: FROM requires either one or three arguments
```

What am I doing wrong?
And is there a way to reference specific platform of the base image if it has been built using `docker buildx`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

update your docker file, you are missing **=**

```
ARG arch
FROM --platform=linux/${arch} bounz/hgbe.base
```

Comment: What's super-confusing is that this option works more like a "target platform", not "source platform". Try specifying the digest of an image with a mismatching platform in FROM — the build will succeed, even without warnings, but will produce an image equal to the --platform you specified.

This is NOT how --platform in `docker run` command works. That option works like "source platform" and will produce an error if you specify an image with a wrong digest.